# Unlink Function Error in Image Uploading

Tags: php, image, unlink

i use this script to upload images for particular products but onece its done, again i use similar image to upload, it updates the information in it but does not show the same image but when i change the name of image it renders..... no idea what to do with unlink function??????? please help?

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp        = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension   = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

    } else {

        if (file_exists("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $image = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            unlink($image);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you speak like a human? People will be more tempted to help you if you can be bothered to type out full words.

Comment: very sorry buddy :) now happy :)

Comment: Follow-up to Prisoner's comment: you should also bother to indent code and explain what your problem is. You only dump some random code and say "it doesn't work, some times".

Comment: done, its not that it wont work it is working but when i upload same image again it does not render.

Comment: It's because if the file exists, it will not let you upload one with the same name. This line is causing this `if(file_exists("../upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){` - You would need to add something to it to give it a unique name. Or, remove it altogether.

Comment: please help me with this i did everything but no use still... :(